# i want my page refresh only once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making an admin page where I can delete users but when I delete a user I have to refresh the page.

I used header refresh but that refreshed my page multiple times, I want my page refreshed only once.

can you guys help me out?

```js
<?php
$dbcon= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,"register") or die(mysqli_connect_error($dbcon));

$query ="SELECT * FROM users";

$run = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query);

while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($run)){

  $user_id = $row[0];
  $user_name = $row[1];
  $user_pass = $row[2];
  $user_mail = $row[3];
?>

 <tr align="center">
  <td><?php echo $user_id ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $user_name ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $user_pass ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $user_mail ?></td>
  <td><a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $user_id;?>"><button onclick="myFunction()">Verdwijder</button></a></td>
 </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You should get users AFTER your delete query

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment, but... Pay attention, that this is a **really bad** practice to mix HTML and PHP code, especially the way you are doing it. I strongly suggest using a proper templating framework, eg. Twig or Smarty (I recommend Twig). Also, it is always better to use associative row names, not numeric. The way you do this, you will have to change the template any time you modify your users table (add columns etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should make two PHP functions. One for displaying the user list and one for deleting users. Both with different URLs.

Then, consder the following flow:

1. User goes to the user list page
2. User clicks on delete button, which calls DELETE action (delete URL).
3. Delete action deletes record and sends the redirect header **back to the user list action**.
4. User is redirected back to user list action, where the whole loop may repeat itself.

If anything goes wrong in the user deletion function, you have two choices. Either the delete action can show the user list with the additional message. Or - **much better** - it can redirect back to the user list action, but with additional parameter (saved in session, encoded in URL, a cookie etc). This parameter is checked always in user list action and, if present, the appropriate status message is shown. To prevent the status message being displayed twice, you can delete the parameter (cookie, session, etc) just after you read it in user list action (so-called flash messages).

As a general rule, it is good to separate actions displaying UI to user with actions actually doing something (deleting the records, inserting new ones etc). This way you have much more control of the process flow. All decent frameworks allow this approach (eg. in Symfony you can create controller function for GET request on some URL, and another for POST or DELETE request on same URL).

Also, as stated in my comment below your question, you should definitely consider using templating framework to further separate view from logic. Twig and Smarty are choices worth consideration (i vote for Twig).

Comment: thanks for your comments. so you are advicing me this: 1 you go to the delete page 2 you click on delete 3 after you press delete you are redirected to another page 4 you go to the delete page again and this time it is refreshed? or am i totally wrong. i will defenitly take al look at twig.

Comment: In general - yes. With one important remark: the second page (actual delete action) should **not** render anything, only redirect on success/failure to the first page (with user list).

Comment: One more thing. If this is not too late for your code, I also strongly advise using a proper PHP framework. It takes a lot off your shoulders (proper routing, security etc). Symfony as a whole is a good choice. Many people also use Zend. Or even Silex, if you prefer microframeworks. Similary, Laravel gets much attention lately. I personally code in Symfony, but choose, what's best for you and your current skills.

Comment: Then, if this works, please, accept the answer :) If this does not, well, accept another (you can also add your own answer and accept it). It is a custom of StackOverflow, you know and users not accepting answers are penalized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
1) Location reload() 
2) window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code i hope it will help.

```
if($queryfired){
echo '<script>alert("Record Deleted:")</script>';
echo '<script>window.location.href="somepage.php";</script>';
}
```

Comment: @Furkan If this answer is useful please vote up that this answer is useful.